# MySQL select help

Tags: sql, mysql

Hi I have a table that looks like this

```
id : productid : featureid
(1, 1, 16)  
(2, 1, 21)  
(3, 1, 25)  
(4, 2, 16)  
(5, 2, 21)  
(6, 2, 27)
```

where featureid is a foreign key to another table.

I need to select products that have both featureids of 16 and 25, in the example this would be `productid 1` but not `productid 2`.

Can someone show me an example of how to format this query?

Answer (score 2):

To get all products which have both features, you can use a sub-query, and then use `Group By` with `Having`-clause to only return those products which have both features (assuming that `productId, featureId` is unique in your table).

```
Select productId
From (
  Select productId
  From your_table
  Where featureId In ( 16, 25 )
)
Group By productId
Having Count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand the last statement about "productid 1 but not productid 2".

I haven't tested this code, but you can do something like this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM `products` AS a INNER JOIN `products` AS b ON ( a.`productid` = b.`product_id` WHERE `featureid` = 25 ) WHERE a.`featureid` = 16
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `featureid` = 16 AND `product_id` IN ( SELECT `productid`FROM `products` WHERE `featureid` = 25 )
```

Comment: i meant the statement will result in productid 1 as it has both featureids 16 & 25